# Doctrine2 Query Builder

Tags: запрос, symfony, doctrine2

Есть запрос:

```
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('o')
   ->from('AppBundle:Order', 'o')
   ->where('o.status = :shipped')
   ->orderBy('o.purchaseDate', 'DESC')
   ->setParameter('shipped', 'shipped');
   ->setMaxResults(10);

$tracked_orders = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

В базе 216 записей, и почему-то делается 216 запросов к базе, отдельный запрос для каждой сущности... С Query Builder'ом работаю первый день, помогите разобраться с тем что я делаю не так?

P.S. Когда использую getArrayResult() - происходит всего 1 запрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, вопрос закрыт. Одно из полей сущности Order было связано one-to-one с другой сущностью, а так как в запросе не было явного join'а доктрина сама дозапрашивала у базы соответствующие данные отдельными запросами.